# SftpClient using Url instead of IP as host

Tags: c#, ssh, ftp, sftp

I am using the following code to upload a file to an `sFTP` server. I have done a test upload using *FileZilla* and the file is uploaded successfully.

```
try
{
    var client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password);
    client.Connect();
    client.ChangeDirectory(workingDir);
    var listDirectory = client.ListDirectory(workingDir);
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024; // bypass payload error large files
        client.UploadFile(fileStream, Path.GetFileName(file));
        Log.Info(string.Format("File [{0}] upload complete",file));
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Error(ex.Message);
}
```

But in the code above, I cannot seem to get the upload done because I get the following error:

> No such host is known

And that's maybe because I am using the Url value of my host instead of IP? (I have done a test with another FtP server using IP and that also seems to be working) I'm wondering if that's the case? If so, is there a way to let `SftpClient` ([Ssh.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET/)) handle the Url?

Comment: The host parameter may be an IP address or a host name that can be resolved to an IP address. It may obviously not be a URL, that is something completely different.

Comment: @arkascha does `ftp.staging.blahblahblah.com/ContactImport` not look like a name? FileZilla does not seem to have a problem with it but my program does.

Comment: No, that looks to me like a string that may be interpreted as part host name, part path. It is neither a URL nor a host name. A host name would be `ftp.staging.blahblahblah.com`.

Comment: The fact that some full application accepts something else than a host name says little: it slits that string into separat tokens and connects to the IP address it gets returned when resolving the host name. You cannot open any network connection to a URL or some arbitrary string, but only to an IP address.

Comment: @arkascha you were right. I should have added ´/ContactImport´ to a separate parameter. It should not be a part of the host name. You can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The host parameter may be an IP address or a host name that can be resolved to an IP address. It may not be a URL, that is something completely different from a technical point of view.

The fact that some full application accepts something else than a host name says little: it splits that string into separat tokens and connects to the IP address it gets returned when resolving the host name. But that does not mean that you can open any network connection to a URL or some arbitrary string. It is only possible to open a connection to an IP address.

So if you successfully test some URL like `sftp://ftp.example.com/ContactImport` in some "program", this does not mean that you can internally use that string as host parameter in your code. You need to use the host name that is a part of such URL, so `ftp.example.com` in this case, since only that can be successfully resolved to an IP address.

Comment: Wow dude thank you so much. I am not very experienced with sending SFTP and was confused because when i sent an FTP i would use the ftp://.... url so I assumed that SFTP would be the same thing. I was mistaken. Your answer helped quite a bit thank you.

Comment: @Lostaunaum `sftp` and `ftp` are two very different things. They appear similar in how they are used, but that is about it. `ftps` and `ftp` are much closer, based on the same base protocol. But even they use separate protocol schemes in URLs for good reasons...